# How to render checkbox without hidden field in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox, struts2, struts-tags

When we create Struts2 checkbox using below code

```jsp
<s:checkbox name="checkMe" fieldValue="true" label="Check Me for testing"/>
```

It gives below HTML representation (I am referring to https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckbox-checkbox-example/)

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkMe" value="true" id="xx_checkMe"/>
<input type="hidden" id="__checkbox_xx_checkMe" name="__checkbox_checkMe" value="true"/>
<label for="resultAction_checkMe" class="checkboxLabel">Check Me for testing</label>
```

Is there anyway to eliminate creating hidden parameter because it is causing security vulnerability for my application

Comment: The hidden parameter is a feature, it is used by the Checkbox Interceptor. What kind of security vulnerability do you believe it is creating ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios MongoDB NOSQL injection. Tool was able to append special  characters to that hidden parameter and pass to backend.

Comment: It is just a hidden input. An input but hidden. Just input. Your *tool* can append special character to any input. You need to sanitize your inputs, not remove hidden fields.

Comment: @AleksandrM. As it is generated by framework, I don't have any control on it to sanitize

Comment: It is created for checkbox, in your case `checkMe`. Can you sanitize this?

Comment: I did sanitize the checkbox that is why tool is not able to append any special characters to checkMe. But it was able to append to __checkbox_checkMe.

Comment: And? Did you use `__checkbox_checkMe` somewhere in your code? You need to sanitize your mongo inputs.

Comment: @AleksandrM I did not use __checkbox_checkMe anywhere in my code. It is the hidden parameter generated by Struts2 for checkbox. I changed Struts2 checkbox to HTML checkbox and used hidden parameter to pass value from UI to backend and sanitized both of them. It passed the scan.  I was curious on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used a freemarker template `checkbox.ftl` to generate html output. You can copy from the source archive and modify this template, then use `template` and `templateDir` attributes to point to the custom template.

Or use archived template, but you need to add `velocity` and `velocity-tools` dependencies.

```jsp
<s:checkbox name="checkme" template="checkbox.vm" templateDir="template/archive"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.